# Serilog middleware and custom middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have implemented some serilog middleware as described in the following blog :https://blog.datalust.co/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core I also have some other custom middleware that occurs after it in the pipeline. I also have some error handling middleware.

If my custom middleware throws an exception then somehow the status code returned from my API is different to the status code being logged. Eg I get back a 401 but the serilog middleware is logging both a 401 and also a 500.

Anyone any ideas what might be issue.

Comment: `LogException()` in the sample assumes that an uncaught exception will result in a 500, but it doesn't set the `Response.StatusCode` itself. If middleware running higher up in the pipeline catches the exception and sets the status code to something different, then the logs and actual response might be out of sync in the way that you describe.

Comment: Showing some of your `Configure()` method (the relevant `app.Use...()` calls), as well as the code from any custom middleware involved, might make it easier to give a useful answer to this one. HTH!

Comment: Your comment makes sense - the error handling middleware does do some setting of  the the status code. 
I tried putting the error handling middleware before the logging middleware and this seems to result in the correct thing being logged.